# How to compile the move_base package

Tags: navigation, move-base, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All,
I want to modify the code in the move_base package and compile.I downloaded the source code of the move_base package, and there were some errors when run "rosmake move_base":

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/6875be8ac068fc67da5b10e950d1e61f

How can I compile the move_base package?

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227502/how-to-compile-the-move_base-package/) by [redskydeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/22936/redskydeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 118 on 2016-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't tell us which specific version of ROS you're using, but `move_base` has not been a `rosmake` package since at least 2013.

It should compile with `catkin_make`, but you'll have to create a catkin workspace for that first. See [wiki/catkin/Tutorials/create a workspace](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace) for some more information.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [redskydeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/22936/redskydeng/) on 2016-02-25**:
I am using ROS indigo.Thank you very much!